# Keep Dots in R Chart Looking The Same When No Data in One Series

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I am creating a dot plot in R using ggplot2. Sometimes this chart contains one series, sometimes two. When it contains two series the chart looks correct, with a red dot for district data and blue crosses for target data.

When only the target data series is present the look of the dots is incorrect, with the target dots shown as red dots rather than blue crosses. See examples. Can you help? Thanks!

Good chart with red dots for the district and blue crosses for the targets:

[image]

Bad chart with red dots for the targets:

[image]

Reproducible example:

```
# Create example data
TEMP_DISTRICT <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, 11, 5))
names(TEMP_DISTRICT) <- c("YEAR",
                            "AMAO_1_CURR_PERCENT_PROGRESS",
                            "AMAO_1_CURR_YEAR_LOWER_CI",
                            "AMAO_1_CURR_YEAR_UPPER_CI",
                            "GROUP")

TEMP_DISTRICT[1, 1] <- 2014
TEMP_DISTRICT[2, 1] <- 2011
TEMP_DISTRICT[3, 1] <- 2012
TEMP_DISTRICT[4, 1] <- 2013
TEMP_DISTRICT[5, 1] <- 2014
TEMP_DISTRICT[6, 1] <- 2015
TEMP_DISTRICT[7, 1] <- 2016
TEMP_DISTRICT[8, 1] <- 2017
TEMP_DISTRICT[9, 1] <- 2018
TEMP_DISTRICT[10, 1] <- 2019
TEMP_DISTRICT[11, 1] <- 2020

TEMP_DISTRICT[1, 2] <- 0
TEMP_DISTRICT[2, 2] <- 0.065
TEMP_DISTRICT[3, 2] <- 0.08
TEMP_DISTRICT[4, 2] <- 0.095
TEMP_DISTRICT[5, 2] <- 0.11
TEMP_DISTRICT[6, 2] <- 0.125
TEMP_DISTRICT[7, 2] <- 0.14
TEMP_DISTRICT[8, 2] <- 0.155
TEMP_DISTRICT[9, 2] <- 0.17
TEMP_DISTRICT[10, 2] <- 0.185
TEMP_DISTRICT[11, 2] <- 0.20

TEMP_DISTRICT[1, 3] <- 0
TEMP_DISTRICT[1, 4] <- 0.793

TEMP_DISTRICT[1, 5] <- "District"
TEMP_DISTRICT[2, 5] <- "Target"
TEMP_DISTRICT[3, 5] <- "Target"
TEMP_DISTRICT[4, 5] <- "Target"
TEMP_DISTRICT[5, 5] <- "Target"
TEMP_DISTRICT[6, 5] <- "Target"
TEMP_DISTRICT[7, 5] <- "Target"
TEMP_DISTRICT[8, 5] <- "Target"
TEMP_DISTRICT[9, 5] <- "Target"
TEMP_DISTRICT[10, 5] <- "Target"
TEMP_DISTRICT[11, 5] <- "Target"

# Good chart
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(TEMP_DISTRICT, aes(x = YEAR, y = AMAO_1_CURR_PERCENT_PROGRESS, group = GROUP))
p +     geom_segment(aes(x = YEAR, y = AMAO_1_CURR_YEAR_LOWER_CI, xend = YEAR, yend = AMAO_1_CURR_YEAR_UPPER_CI), na.rm = TRUE) +
        geom_point(aes(colour = GROUP, shape = GROUP)) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), labels = percent) + # Make y axis percent
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2011:2021) + # Set x axis labels
        xlab("School Year") +
        ylab("Percent Progressing") + 
        ggtitle("Current Year Percent Progressing") + 
        labs(shape = NULL, colour = NULL) + # Remove legend title
        scale_colour_hue(breaks = c("District","Target")) + # Order legend labels
        scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,3), breaks = c("District", "Target")) +
        theme_classic()
rm(p)

# Bad chart
TEMP_DISTRICT <- subset(TEMP_DISTRICT, GROUP == "Target")

p <- ggplot(TEMP_DISTRICT, aes(x = YEAR, y = AMAO_1_CURR_PERCENT_PROGRESS, group = GROUP))
p +     geom_segment(aes(x = YEAR, y = AMAO_1_CURR_YEAR_LOWER_CI, xend = YEAR, yend = AMAO_1_CURR_YEAR_UPPER_CI), na.rm = TRUE) +
        geom_point(aes(colour = GROUP, shape = GROUP)) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), labels = percent) + # Make y axis percent
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2011:2021) + # Set x axis labels
        xlab("School Year") +
        ylab("Percent Progressing") + 
        ggtitle("Current Year Percent Progressing") + 
        labs(shape = NULL, colour = NULL) + # Remove legend title
        scale_colour_hue(breaks = c("District","Target")) + # Order legend labels
        scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,3), breaks = c("District", "Target")) +
        theme_classic()
rm(p)
```

Comment: Do you want to keep `District` in the legend even when it isn't part of the graph?

Comment: It would be ok either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague (http://www.jaredknowles.com) provided the solution for this question offline. See scale_colour_manual and scale_shape_manual:

shapes1 <- c("District" = 16, "Target" = 3)
colors1 <- c("District" = "firebrick1", "Target" = "deepskyblue")

p <- ggplot(TEMP_DISTRICT, aes(x = YEAR, y = AMAO_1_CURR_PERCENT_PROGRESS, group = GROUP))
p +     geom_segment(aes(x = YEAR, y = AMAO_1_CURR_YEAR_LOWER_CI, xend = YEAR, yend = AMAO_1_CURR_YEAR_UPPER_CI), na.rm = TRUE) +
        geom_point(aes(colour = GROUP, shape = GROUP)) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), labels = percent) + # Make y axis percent
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2011:2021) + # Set x axis labels
        xlab("School Year") +
        ylab("Percent Progressing") + 
        ggtitle("Current Year Percent Progressing") + 
        labs(shape = NULL, colour = NULL) + # Remove legend title
        scale_colour_manual(values = colors1) +
        scale_shape_manual(values = shapes1) +
        theme_classic()